# borders in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML And CSS. In my CSS file, I have the following:

```
html {
 border-top: 4px solid #000000;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
 border-left: 4px solid #000000;
 border-right: 4px solid #000000;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #000000;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: serif;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.bot-img {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

When I open the page in Chrome, it looks ok - like so:

[image: chrome]

When I open the page in Firefox, it looks, like so:

[image]

How would I make both match?

**Edit:**

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
        <title>TheTitle</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% load flatpages %}
            {% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
            {% for flatpage in flatpages %}
        <img class="bot-img"  src="{% static 'img/bottomband.jpg' %}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm developing this with Django 1.5(and MySQL) as the backend.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: try to give `overflow:hidden` to html and body.

Comment: The rendered HTML, not the template you have there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be across your entire html view, you should add the following to your CSS

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also I recommend you refactor your border code to the following:

```
html {
  border: 4px solid #000000;
}
```

This just prevents you from having to repeat the same line of code four times.

Hope this helps.